# Proof for Total Overhead Formula for IPv4 Fragmentation

Tags: induction

I am struggling to develop a proof for an equation to compute the total bandwidth required for fragmented IP packets.

When a router forwards an IPv4 packet of size $n$ over a link with an MTU $m$ then the packet will be fragmented if $n>m$. Each fragment imposes an overhead of $o$ bytes (typically, $o=20$).

It looks like you could define this process recursively, where the size of each fragment is $F_i=m$ and $F_{i+1}=n-m+o$.

Total number of packets, with our without fragmentation, is $1 + \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor$. The first packet does not impose any additional overhead, so the total overhead from subsequent fragments should be $o \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor$.

For example, a 4500-byte packet traversing a link with an MTU of 1500 bytes will be fragmented into packets of sizes $F_0=1500$, $F_1=1480+20$, $F_2=1480+20$, and $F_3=40+20$.

The total number of fragments is $\lfloor \frac{4500}{1500} \rfloor = 3$ and the resulting overhead is $3\cdot20=60$ bytes.

We should be able to compute the total data transferred as

$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle
F_0 + F_1 + ... + F_{\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor} & = \\\\
\sum_{p\in F} p & = o\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor + n
\end{align}
$

This looks like something I should be able to prove with induction, but we never dealt with inequalities like this in school. I think the base case should be $m \lt n_1 \le 2m-o$ (ugly, I know). This should result in one fragment with $o$ bytes of overhead.

$
\begin{align}
F_0 + F_1 & = \sum_{p\in F} p \\\\
(m) + (n - m + o) & = o\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor + n \\\\
n + o & = o \cdot 1 + n
\end{align}
$

How do I go about constructing the inductive step? I'm thinking you assume $cm < k < (c+1)m - o$ for $c \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ then the next step should be $k+m$, which adds one additional fragment and $o$ bytes of overhead, right?

Comment: This is the wrong forum for your question.  If you have k many fragments, you are sending at most km bits, of which (k-1)o are over head, so n is less than the difference.  I think this helps with a non recursive proof.  Gerhard "Verify This With Small Cases" Paseman, 2017.08.23.